# Maven 3.0.3 ignoring environment variables

Tags: visual-c++, maven, environment-variables

I have an interesting issue with Maven 3 in eclipse choosing which environment variables it wishes to run.  Some environment variables I pass into my MSVC compiler work properly, such as setting this variable...

```
            <linkerStartOption>/LIBPATH:"${env.JAVA_X86HOME}/lib"</linkerStartOption>
```

will result in CL output...

```
            cmd.exe /X /C "link.exe /LIBPATH:"C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_24/lib"
```

however other variables written in the same way will result in output like this...

```
            cmd.exe /X /C "link.exe /LIBPATH:"${env.ExampleVar}\lib\amd64"
```

and is simply not stripping the value I need from that environment variable.  I have googled the issue and simply ran into other people also having the issue, however no solution is defined for it.  Anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: ANSWER:  Maven 3 requires environmental variables to be upper case apparently.

Comment: ran into the same issue - glad someone solved it already. Thanks